# ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre una clase abstracta y una interface?

Tags: java, clase, clase-abstracta, interface

**Hola, un saludo, y muchas gracias por ayudarme.**

La duda que tengo es ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre una clase abstracta y una interface?. Veo que son conceptos  parecidos , he captado la idea de que las clases abstractas no son instanciable pero lo que quisiera saber exactamente si es posible, cuando se debe utilizar cada uno o en qué casos es mejor, o para que específicamente son utilizadas.

Comment: la clase abstracta por definición se usa para ser heredar datos a unas clase hija, como datos, como métodos generales que recrean comportamiento común.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola te voy a dar una respuesta un poco mas informal que las que te dieron:

En una Jerarquía de clases cuando apliques herencia vas a tener métodos que la implementación es igual para todas las clases
Pero por ahí vas a necesitar un método que NO se va a implementar del mismo modo en las clases que heredan.
Entonces en la clase padre para decir: necesito que las clases que hereden "tengan estas funcionalidades", pero este método va a tener que tener diferente implementación en cada clase, eso lo solucionarías creando un método abstracto y cuando declaras un método abstracto, por obligación la clase va a tener que ser abstracta.
Eso te va a obligar en las clase que heredes a sobrescribir solo el método abstracto.

Con la Interfaces también obligas a que sobrescriban e implementen la lógica, pero tenés que hacerlo en todos los métodos.

Espero que mi comentario te guie un poco más. saludos!

Comment: Trata de obtener reputación para agregar comentarios. Revisar [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias diferencias entre una clase abstracta y una interfaz:

1. Una clase abstracta puede heredar o extender cualquier clase (independientemente de que esta sea abstracta o no), mientras que una interfaz solamente puede extender o implementar otras interfaces.
2. Una clase abstracta puede heredar de una sola clase (abstracta o no) mientras que una interfaz puede extender varias interfaces de una misma vez.
3. Una clase abstracta puede tener métodos que sean abstractos o que no lo sean, mientras que las interfaces sólo y exclusivamente pueden definir métodos abstractos.
4. En java concretamente (ya que has puesto la etiqueta Java), en las clases abstractas la palabra abstract es obligatoria para definir un método abstracto (así como la clase). Cuando defines una interfaz, esta palabra es opcional ya que se infiere en el concepto de interfaz.
5. En una clase abstracta, los métodos abstractos pueden ser public o protected. En una interfaz solamente puede haber métodos públicos.
6. En una clase abstracta pueden existir variables static, final o static final con cualquier modificador de acceso (public, private, protected o default). En una interfaz sólo puedes tener constantes (public static final).

La proxima vez escribe tu pregunta en google ya que he puesto tu titulo y me ha sacado lo que te acabo de copiar, y respondiendo a tu pregunta la diferencia mas notable entre una clase abstracta y una interfaz depende de la herencia que van a tener. Solo puedes heredar de una clase pero puedes implementar varias interfaces, entonces normalmente se utiliza una clase abstracta cuando vayas a construir un arbol de herencia como por ejemplo ( Persona es superclase de Niño,Niña,Adulto...) mientras en caso contrario normalmente se utiliza la interfaz debido a que no te prohibe la herencia de otras cosas.

Comment: No está mal, pero los puntos 1 y 2 no quedan muy claros y tienen incorrecciones ya que 1) Una clase abstracta (o no abstracta) no puede heredar de una clase `final`, 2) las clases abstractas, igual que las demás, DEBEN heredar de otra clase (aunque sea la herencia implícita a `Object`), 3) Parece que implicas que solo las interfaces pueden extender múltiples interfaces, cuando las clases abstractas no tienen problema en implementar múltiples interfaces (este punto es algo más sutil, pero realmente creo que deberías explicar la diferencia entre extender e implementar para que quede claro).

Comment: La respuesta de Rosca esta muy completa pero creo que falta lo mas importante que es lo siguiente,
una clase abstracta puede tener algun método implementado, es decir con código, y las interfaces no pueden tener métodos implementados, es decir, sólo estaría escrita la cabecera de los métodos.

Comment: Una interfaz sí puede contener código (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)